# GLSL Fragment Shader: Sampler2D issues

Tags: javascript, canvas, glsl, webgl, fragment-shader

I am trying to create a small game using WebGL. In this game, I want to create multiple sonar effects(a glowing ring traveling outwards from a point) using GLSL.
Each of these sonar effect should however be affected by a different mask. This mask is created and stored in a canvas and linked to the fragment shader using [glsl.js](http://greweb.me/2013/02/glsl-js-a-javascript-glsl-library-dry-efficient/) for ease of use.

I created a object for each of these sonar effects as well as their structs in the Fragment shader. However, when trying to add the mask canvas to it as a Sampler2D type, the shader script dies, giving a non-descriptive error.

This makes me wonder about Sampler2D: Is it impossible to use inside of structs or am I doing something else wrong?

I also tried doing the same thing but this time keeping the Samplers outside of the structs and put them into an array.
However, the fragment shader doesn't like this either. Is it impossible to use arrays of Sampler2D objects?

To summarize:

- Is it possible to use Sampler2D objects inside of structs or not?
- Is it possible to create arrays of Sampler2D objects or not?
- If both of these are impossible: how can I pass the masks to the fragment shader in an other way?

EDIT:

The struct code I am using:

```
struct Sonar{
            float type;//kind of effect, right now only one implemented
            float posx;//xposition of effect
            float posy;//yposition of effect
            float incr;//how far the effect is in its animation
            bool alive;//If the effect should be shown
            float strength;//How strong the effect should be
            sampler2D shadows;//Shadow mask
        };
```

Comment: This seems like the perfect scenario for custom [texture LOD access](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Sampler_(GLSL)#Lod_texture_access).

Comment: Can you show the "struct" code you're using?

Comment: Thanks for your replies. @BrettHale: I have never heard about LOD before. Could you tell me how to use it?